# JSF - Add visually custom component to Eclipse web page editor

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, windowbuilder

I am observing eclipse jsf **components palette**; The thing is I couldn't find  is there a way to "add" one jsf to another as gwt or swing provides ?

if to compare to swing or gwt-like code style for example I mean :

```
class MyJFrame extends JFrame{

    MyCanvas(){
       MyJPanel panel0=new MyJPanel();
       panel0.setHouse(HOUSE.GREEN);

       JPanel p=new JPanel();
       p.setLayout(...);
       p.add(panel0);

       MyJPanel panel1=new MyJPanel();
       panel0.setHouse(HOUSE.RED);

       p.add(panel1);//etc

       this.getContentPane().add(p);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I'd like to add component(composite) with eclipse wysiwyg editor to see (in real time) where added "ui" is located (see image);

[image]

and if to compare to jsf web editor in eclipse then it doesn't show any preview of inclusion I do (see image) :(

[image]

...so my question is... is there a way to create complicated UI with jsf and eclipse windowbuilder which suppose to create external objects and then *combining* them visually within one main UI for example? The UI in OOP way as gwt provides?

p.s. sorry if the question is too easy but I really need to know should I keep digging google about that?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure it is a duplicate cause I am asking about wysiwyg eclipse editor and jsf...

Comment: You mean all "composites" in jsf may be added but should be added manually or what? But how to control location?

Comment: Seems like in jsf the polymorphism-alike effect can be realized with facelets or something (correct me if I am wrong); The thing is I'd like to see external jsf (if I add it) in windowbuilder in real time to be sure it is properly located; The thing is when I use "insert"+"include" I don't see any in wysiwyg eclipse editor :( But why?